# Can some help me with the installation of CGNS with cmake and its supporting softwares, namely, hdf5, zlib and szip?

Tags: 14.04

I am using UBUNTU 14.04(64bit OS) and am facing problem in the installation of CGNS latest stable release. Though I have successfully been able to finish my installation of CGNS and its supporting directories(names mentioned in the title), running an associated program file on it shows the following error:

```
$ g++ -Wall -I/usr/local/include -L/usr/local/ prep_tri.cpp -lhdf5 -lcgns
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lhdf5
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
$
```

Can some tell me how to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to install [`libhdf5-7` and `libhdf5-dev`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=hdf5):

```
sudo apt-get install libhdf5-7 libhdf5-dev
```

Comment: I am having problem installing libhdf5-cpp-7. It shows the error:

ravi@ravi-Inspiron-5537:~$ sudo apt-get install libhdf5-cpp-7
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libhdf5-cpp-7

Comment: @PrabhaRaviShankar Ah, sorry. I misread the search results `libhdf5-cpp-7` is for another version of Ubuntu. You can remove that from the command.

Comment: I am facing this problem as I "make" cgns despite having downloaded the files you told. Any help on this please.


make[2]: *** No rule to make target `/usr/lib/libhdf5.so', needed by `src/tools/cgnscheck'.  Stop.
make[1]: *** [src/tools/CMakeFiles/cgnscheck.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2